# How can I update by taking data from textbox fields on a form?

Tags: vb.net

I am making a booking system. I am using same form for insertion and updation. How can I update by taking the values from the textboxes. For example if the user enters value for just 2 out of 8 fields then How can i update just 2 fields without affecting the rest of the record. I mean to say that if I use a single update query using all the fields then if some textbox is left empty then it will replace the database field value by null or something else..Can anyone help me on this???

Answer (score 0):

You need to write code to track which text boxes have changed.  When you load an existing record, for each text box set `.Tag = 0`.  In each `TextBox.Validated` event, set `.Tag = 1`.  When the user presses the update button, you can check which text boxes have `.Tag = 1` and only update those fields.

---

**EDIT based on comment:**

Just create the query string dynamically.

```
Private Function GetUpdateQuery() As String
    Dim Query As New StringBuilder
    Query.Append("UPDATE Table SET ")
    Dim First As Boolean = True
    For Each ColumnTextBox In ColumnTextBoxes
        If First Then
            First = False
        Else
            Query.Append(",")
        End If
        If ColumnTextBox.Tag = 1 Then Query.Append("{0}={1}", ColumnName, ColumnTextBox.Text)
    Next
    Query.Append(" WHERE ID={0}", RecordID)
    Return Query.ToString
End Function
```

Comment: I can keep track of which textboxes have been updated but i want to know how can i change the query for different values

Answer (score 0):

The following code will only update the columns if the values are not `NULL`. If they are, the current value will be saved over itself.

```
UPDATE TableA
SET ColA=ISNULL(@ColA, ColA)
   ,ColB=ISNULL(@ColB, ColB)
   ,ColC=ISNULL(@ColC, ColC)
WHERE ID=@ID
```